# Jquery animate function step parameter not evaluated at each step

Tags: jquery

I want to check one condition specified in the step function of Jquery animate function. But, for some reason the step function is executed only few times and does not seem to be executed every single step of animation. I want to check a condition on every step of movement so that I can then change the animation if condition is met.

Here is the code:

```
// orig position of #testball is 0px left and 0px top
$("#testball").animate({
            left:"500px",
            top :"500px"
            }, {
           speed: "slow",
           step: function(now, fx) {
            alert("hello");

                 if((testball.offsetLeft >= barline5.offsetLeft) && (testball.offsetLeft <= barline5.offsetLeft))
                 {                       
                     testball.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                 }
        }
      });
```

I want the step function to be executed on every small movement of the object. But in this case, the step function is called only 4-5 times when animated from 0px to 500px(I thought it would be executed on every pixel animation). And so the condition is not properly evaluated.

Please share if you know why the step function is not been executed on every small movement.

Answer (score 0):

`step` actually gets called for each property you're animating throughout the animation. So, if you are animating n-number of properties, then step gets called n-number of times during each tween movement.

Personally, I believe `progress` might make more sense for what you're trying to do? (I'm guessing, check a condition after each step of the animation?)

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YWAE5/1/

Because we're animating top and left (***2 properties***), step should be called ***2x*** times more than the progress function. Add additional properties, and that number will continue going up.

(a potential for a performance hit...)